# android crop activity only by intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, crop

I'm doing app which take picture and let user crop his picture.

I did capture activity not by call intent... With many help on the web, my app take picture itself.

Now i would like to let user to crop picture... But on the web, i see everyone using

**EXAMPLE :**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, PIC_CROP);
```

Is there the only way to let user crop image ?
We can't develop our own crop activity (even if it's hard) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there the only way to let user crop image ?

Not only is it not the only way, this approach is seriously flawed. I have [a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html) discussing that and pointing out some libraries that offer cropping.

> We can't develop our own crop activity (even if it's hard) ?

You are welcome to write whatever you want.